# Check if GET is set and then post HTML concatenated with PHP variable

Tags: php, html

Ok, so I have an id passed from the previous page

```
$_GET['id'];
```

I want to check if the id has been set first, and if so, then echo the following code :

EDIT: please also look at http://pastebin.com/P2Jnapnf

EDIT2:

```
 $with = (isset($_GET['with']) && !empty($_GET['with'])) ? '<iframe class="youtube-player"
 type="text/html" width="540" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$_GET['with']. 'frameborder="0">
</iframe>' : false;
```

I tried this but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if variable set and echo the code if it is

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])):?>
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="540" height="385"
       src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" frameborder="0"> 
    </iframe>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following - the `isset` will check if the variable is set (as in it exists) and `!empty` to ensure that the variable actually has data in it:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    // You code here.
}
```

Edit: I would do something like this:

```
$myID = (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) ? 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$_GET['id'] : false;

echo ($myID) ? $myID : "";
```

The first part will do a ternary operator and if `(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))` evaluates to true, it will assign `$myID` the value of your link and the ID from the GET. If not, it will assign a `false` boolean.

The next line uses another ternary and if `$myID` is false, outputs an empty string, otherwise it displays the full link.

Edit 2: Try this:

```
echo (isset($_GET['with']) && !empty($_GET['with'])) ? '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="540" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$_GET['with']. 'frameborder="0"></iframe>' : false;
```

Edit 3: A deceze correctly points out: The `!empty` function will by default call the `isset` function first - meaning that if it isn't set, it *cannot* pass a `!empty` function with anyting else than `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please also look at http://pastebin.com/P2Jnapnf which is the second part of my problem :)

Comment: Please refer to my second edit, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Don't use `isset` *and* `!empty`, it's redundant. [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @deceze Fair call. Have made further edit.

Comment: No luck :(, the ID just doesn't seem to concatenate.